# Propel ORM : Versionable + Concrete Inheritance behaviors issue

Tags: inheritance, foreign-keys, propel

I've got an issue when I use jointly `versionable` and `concrete_inheritance` behaviors :

```
propel > om-template:
[propel-om] Loading XML schema files...
[propel-om] 3 tables found in 1 schema files.
[propel-om] Generating PHP files...
[propel-om]     -> Updating Library/Model/om/BaseBookPeer.php (table: book, builder: PHP5PeerBuilder)
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getPhpName() on a non-object in 
  C:\wamp\www\library\vendor\propel\propel1\generator\lib\behavior\versionable\VersionableBehaviorObjectBuilderModifier.php on line 313
```

Here a simplified example to explain it :

[image: UML Schema]

Everything is versionable. **The simple `Page-Cover` pattern doesn't cause any issue, `Book-Page` neither. But when I start using the 3 tables I've got the previous error.**

Usually, we've got this error using foreign keys and a global `auto_add_pk` behaviors (as behaviors are interpreted after foreign keys, propel can't find the primary key in the referred table).

My `schema.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database name="library" namespace="Library\Model" defaultIdMethod="native">

    <table name="book">
        <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
        <column name="title" type="varchar" size="255" required="true" primaryString="true" />
        <!-- #### This following behavior is my problem #### -->
        <behavior name="versionable">
            <parameter name="log_created_at" value="true" />
            <parameter name="log_created_by" value="true" />
            <parameter name="log_comment" value="true" />
        </behavior>
    </table>

    <table name="page">
        <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
        <column name="num" type="integer" required="true" />
        <column name="text" type="longvarchar"/>
        <column name="book_id" type="integer" required="true" />
        <foreign-key foreignTable="book">
            <reference local="book_id" foreign="id"/>
        </foreign-key>
        <behavior name="versionable">
            <parameter name="log_created_at" value="true" />
            <parameter name="log_created_by" value="true" />
            <parameter name="log_comment" value="true" />
        </behavior>
    </table>

    <table name="cover">
        <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
        <behavior name="concrete_inheritance">
            <parameter name="extends" value="page" />
        </behavior>
    </table>

</database>
```

Any suggestion to help me understand ?

Comment: Not sure exactly what the issue is, but did you mean for the `cover` table to have two `id` columns? My guess is this is a typo as I think you would get other errors first. Also, since concrete inheritance pulls in all columns from the parent table, I think you'd actually end up with 3 `id` columns. Maybe take that out of `cover` and see what you get?

Comment: The double `id` was a typo. I use to redefine `id` columns with concrete inheritance, and never had any problem. But this is an interesting point, I'll try to remove `cover.id` tomorrow.

Comment: My experience with versionable is limited, so I may not be much more help... have you tried the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/propel-users)?

Comment: FYI, I'm writing a test case for this to see if I can replicate. I'll let you know what I find.